# Почему фронт не работает по прямой ссылке?

Tags: java, angular2, spring-boot

Делал фронт через Ангулар, бек через Спринг фрейм. 
Есть роутинг с начальной страницы в app компоненте

---

ts:

```
onNavigate(url: string): void {
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

}

---

По такому примеру прописаны переходы в html

```
<button class="submenu" mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['entrance']">Entrance</button>
```

Суть в чем: если переходить по кнопкам все работает, но если перейти по прямой ссылке ( localhost:4200/entrance ), к примеру, то выдает длинный список ошибок

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "entrance"
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:

И так еще ~100. А если выключить бекенд, выдает такое:

> Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/entrance

Причем бекенд ранится на порте 8082, а фронт на 4200. Об'ясните пожалуйста почему. Это мой первый проект на ангуляре и спринге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен, просто фронтенд запускался через прокси с портом бекенда.